# How to deal with disconnected components in isomap?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

While creating a nearest neighbor graph for isomap, there is a possibility that the graph is disconnected. In this case finding graph distances between all pairs of points will not be possible. Are there any simple methods other than iteratively changing the nearest neighbor search parameters  till we get a connected graph?

Answer (score 0):

I believe here is a solution: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8282172.

Short summary: Build the network and get disconnected graphs. Calculate the center of each small graph and connect the centers with each other. Then scale the edges connecting different small graphs by some number greater than 1.

Comment: Try to expand a bit the answer with the contents of your link. Links can become obsolete so a text reference of what was on the link is needed in case the link goes 404 in the future.